# draggable with margins doesn't work correctly in Chromium only

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, jquery-ui-draggable

I've a draggable as follows:

```
<div id="_splitter" style="width: 40px; height: 40px; position: relative; z-index: 1; margin: -20px -23px auto auto; border: 3px solid gray; opaciy:.5;"></div>
```

In Chrome it works correctly only until the first mouseup event. Once the div is dragged to a new position, the next drag shifts the element to the top-left by the size of the margins, so it looks like a sudden jump when you start dragging it for the second time.

The problem only occurs in Chrome, FF & Opera work just fine. Could anyone advice on how do I get it working in Chrome?

**Note**: I'd like to find a fix, rather than a hack, I kind of know that if I remove/re-add draggable it'll probably work, but that's not what I'm after.

Here's a repro HTML, sorry have no fiddle:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>draggable</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.21/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $("#_splitter").draggable();
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <div id="_splitter" 
            style="width: 40px; height: 40px; position: relative; z-index: 1; margin: 100px auto auto 100px; border: 3px solid gray; background-color: Green;"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you make a fiddle showing your problem?

Comment: your code works fine http://jsbin.com/ajiram/2/edit.

Comment: it does not. pay attention to the second drag watch the position of the green box in Chrome. it offsets the mouse position, which shouldn't happen.

Comment: @EH_warch sorry mate, didn't see the link - it does work fine in the bin, but when I copy the contents of the window the bug re-appears.

Comment: @user1514042 that means the error is somewhere else, update the jsbin with a more accurate approximation of your code and pass the link back.

Comment: I posted the entire contents of the page, on which it doesn't work. I don't want to deal with bins/fiddles - I just need to get it working on my tiny little page. Just copy the html from my post above.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me. I just reorganized it in JSFiddle, just cut and paste.

Check it here [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uRbmw/5/)